# How to assign object tab to one profile

Tags: apex, administration, permission-sets

One custom object is perfectly viewable as an admin. But in my org, one profile users needs to be able to view this tab and right now He can't. How to viewable to that particular profile user?  Should i use permission set or what?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to tab visibility there are three possible options:

```
1. None - Tab is not at all accessible to the user. 
2. Available - The tab cannot be found in the top breadcrumb of the salesforce UI but can be accessed from the all tabs page.(or even directly via URL).
3. Visible - The tab is accessible from the top bread crumb as well as the all tabs page( or directly via URL).
```

Now providing tab visibility to an user:
This can be done via profile or by permission sets. Permission are additive - so in case of conflicting permissions - the less restrictive ones win.

If you provide your tab visibility by profile, then every user who has that profile will have appropriate visibility to tab. You can no longer give a more restrictive visibility to any of the profile users.

Another finer way of controlling tab visibility is to provide a no visibility in profile and the control the tab visibility using permission set assignments. You can create a permission set that provided tab visibility and assign that permission set to users within the profile, now only those users will have tab visibility. This way you control tab visibility finer/more selective than what profile allows you to. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. As this is for single user then create a permission set and give tab permission and now assign this to the user. it will solve your problem with just point and click.

Comment: Hi @Tushar Sharma There are 10 users under that profile. Every user under that profile needs to be viewable that object.

Comment: So @chris in that case give permission at profile level. Tab will be hidden change that setting.

Comment: The custom tab setting for that object is default on. Even the user not able to view the custom object as a tab

Comment: check on profile level. also click on + icon. there you will find this tab and add this in navigation.